# Debugging error : ./vamsitest.sh: line 10: [: missing `]'

Tags: shell, shell-script

script : it is giving below error. basically i need to get email when memory exceeds some limit.

```
error : ./vamsitest.sh: line 10: [: missing `]'
```

```
#! /bin/bash

# Total memory space details

echo "Memory Space Details"
free -t -m | grep "Total" | awk '{ print "Total Memory space : "$2 " MB";
        print "Used Memory Space : "$3" MB";
        print "Free Memory : "$4" MB";
    }'
if [ "$3" MB" >10000 MB];
then
    email -s "memory utilization is high" vamsi.muluguru@gmail.com
fi
```

Comment: Seriously? It tells you what line has a problem, and still you don't notice that it has three quotes (i.e., they're not balanced)? ... ... ... Also, you can't use `>` inside `[…]` like that. You should probably leave off the units (`MB`) and compare the numbers with `-gt`.

Comment: And space before the closing `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variable $3 is undefined. You seem to be assuming it is the awk variable $3. And you use wrong syntax (quoting!) in the shell test operation.

Do everything in shell, or do everything in awk.

In awk...

```
echo "Memory Space Details"
free -t -m | awk '
    /Total/ {
        print "Total Memory space : "$2 " MB"
        print "Used Memory Space : "$3" MB"
        print "Free Memory : "$4" MB"
        if ($3 > 10000)
            system ("email -s ...")
    }'
```

In shell (e.g. bash)...

```
echo "Memory Space Details"
set $( free -t -m | grep "Total")
printf "Total Memory space : %s MB\n" "$2"
printf "Used Memory Space : %s MB\n" "$3"
printf "Free Memory : %s MB\n" "$4"
(( $3 > 10000 ))  &&  email -s "..."
```

Comment: Hi Jains, Can you help me how to write shell if i have to check memory for 3 stand alone servers which are shared diff jobs for one application. can you please tell me how to pass the server names in shell script?

Comment: This is a completely unrelated question I suppose? Then please open a new question in StackEnxchange. And try to describe your problem more accurately. For a start: pass the server names as arguments to your script. `yourscript yourservername` and access that name in your script as `$1`.